# Generate date series using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a closing date and delivery date column, if the date difference greater than 1 then, I need to generate date series with a closing date column. I have attached the example closing date and delivery date details below.

[image: Current -> Closing date and Delivery Date]

I want the output to be like the below one

[image: Expected result]

Please help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this extended table and the following code I believe you would get the desired results:

```
Closing | Delivery | Difference | Order
---------------------------------------
190228  | 190321   | 21         | A
190228  | 190301   | 1          | B
190310  | 190317   | 7          | C
```

```
ExpandedDeliveryTable = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    FILTER(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            CROSSJOIN(
                CALCULATETABLE(
                    'Deliveries';
                    'Deliveries'[Difference] > 1
                );
                GENERATESERIES(
                    0;
                    MAX('Deliveries'[Difference]);
                    1
                )
            );
            "Filter"; 
            IF( [Delivery]-[Closing] < [Value]; 1; BLANK() )
        );
        [Filter] <> 1
    );
    "Closing_Date"; [Closing]+[Value];
    "DeliveryDate"; [Delivery];
    "Date Diff"; [Value];
    "Order"; [Order]
)
```

This generates a new table looking like this:

[image]]

Comment: Found a bug in my first version, is should obviously be [Closing]+[Value] when creating [Closing_Date] in the SELECTCOLUMNS function.

Comment: If my closing date/delivery date is blank will this work?

Comment: This code does not take care of blank dates. However, it depends on how you calculate the difference column. If the difference is negative it will not be calculated, on the other hand, if the difference is bigger than 1 it will be included. If this is a issue for you just make sure both Closing and Delivery dates are non-blank when calculating the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I am trying to understand your code, I would like to know why you have used "[Filter] <> 1" what is the purpose ? .

Comment: The IF-statement above checks if [Value] is larger than the difference between the two dates. If it is it's set to 1, otherwise it's blank. The [Filter] <> 1 keeps the rows in the table which are blank. This as to be done because the GENERATESERIES uses the maximum of the difference column. So in my case, Order = C exist as 22 lines for a short period but the IF and filter makes sure its only 0-7 (i.e 8 rows) which are kept

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.